# Method to test FTP connection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, ftp

I would need a simple method (`objective-C`) that tests given `FTPdata` (url, username, password) and checks if it is possible to connect to the `FTP`. If not, it should return the error telling whats wrong. could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some sample code available.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer.. i have already implemented this in my code. problem is that i need to see if i can connect.. without uploading anything.. only connect. and if not return the error message. the codeprovide doesnt do this, and only returns a generic error. thanks